# Verbose Error reporting in iPhone Safari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, error-handling, safari

So we have a large JS web-app running on our server, whose majority audience are running it off mobile browsers - mostly Safari on Iphones. JS errors are caught using Airbrake Error Catcher. However, investigating live bugs that appear via Airbrake is frustrating due to Safari truncating its error messages. What outputs as this on desktop browsers:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'blah.currency_symbol')**

appears as below on Safari iPhone:

**'undefined' is not an object**

So unless I know how or where to reproduce the error, I've no way of knowing what's going wrong & where.

Long story short - is there anyway of capturing more verbose error information from Safari iPhone? I tested using try/catch but the object still only returned the truncated message.

*(apologies if this has been asked before, no searches seemed to yield answers)*

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, no responses but I think from my own further tests the answer might be an insurmountable 'no' - I did the simplest test I could think of, binding to the error object and capturing the error response in the callback. It seems that the truncated error (e.message) is the main form of the response iOS Safari uses, and even other standard values in the object - such as filename or linenumber - aren't being set at all. Seems like before the object is even passed back to the console Safari truncates it 'helpfully' :(